# Start and stop multiple executable for easy debugging

Tags: networking, process, scripting, debugging

I'm debugging a networking project, which involves interacting of 3 programs, ie a server, two different clients. However I find it difficult to start and stop them for debugging. Some methods I have tried so far:

- Start 3 terminals. Run `./server`, `./client1`, `./client2`. The problem with this method is I need to switch back and forth between windows.
- Start 1 terminal. Put these in a script: `./server &;./client1 &;./client2 &`. Run the script. The problem with this method is killing the processes after debugging is hard. Need to look up PID and type `kill <PID>`.

Is there a better way to do this? How do people usually debug in that situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make something like this your launch script:

```
./server & server_pid=$!
./client1 & client1_pid=$!
./client2 & client2_pid=$!
echo 'kill "$@"' "$server_pid $client1_pid $client2_pid" >.kill.sh
```

And call `./kill.sh` to kill all the processes. The key point is to use `$!` to retrieve the PID of the last backgrounded command, You may prefer other methods for storing it and later making use of it.

Comment: Why did you write the dot in the beginning of the filename? `.kill.sh`